# Host-only openSUSE VMWare Player guest not pingable from Windows 7 host

Tags: windows-7, networking, vmware-player, opensuse-12.2

I'm running VMWare Player 5.0.1 build-894247 on my Windows 7 computer.  I need to have the openSUSE virtual machine run with a static IP but only be accessible by the host (i.e. not be on the network).  When I set the guest to Host-only rather than NAT I can no longer ping the guest (or access it on any port from the host).  My host is on a 10.10.x.x subnet and my guest is using 192.168.x.x, and unfortunately I can't change that.  Am I out of luck or just missing something?

Comment: It's possible that I'm insane and NAT is what I wanted all along.  I thought I had tested being able to ping the VM using NAT from other physical computers but maybe not since now nobody can see the VM but me when I use NAT.